# How to encrypt a string at compile-time and decrypt it at runtime in Rust, similar to constexpr encryption in c++?

Tags: rust

In c++, It's possible to use some tricks with the help of constexpr, to write a MACRO that encrypts strings in compile-time, and decrypts them in runtime, and we could use something like `ENCRYPT("MyString")` to achieve this. An example is the following header file:

https://github.com/skadro-official/skCrypter/blob/master/files/skCrypter.h

Is this also possible in Rust? I want to encrypt my strings in compile time, and decrypt them in runtime.

Comment: You'd probably want to use a procedural macro or a build script to do it. I think it'd technically be possible via [const functions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/const_eval.html) but they are still quite limited so it would be a huge hassle as it would not allow easy use of existing crypto packages (I doubt many of any of them supports compile-time evaluation).

Comment: @Masklinn Is there any open source rust project that is doing what I'm asking? There are a lot of c++ projects for this, but I cannot find any rust project for it :(

Comment: The closest thing would be [`std::cell::OnceCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.OnceCell.html) and the string would be encrypted only once using the closure passed to the `get_or_init()` function. __Unfortunately at runtime.__